ROS2 robot_localization how to correct x and y position when hit a wall
I started using the robot_localization EKF node recently to fuse encoder odometry and IMU data (I'm using a differential robot with 2 wheels). It works well because if I rotate the robot by hand, the odometry rotates too, even if the wheels aren't moving. The only problem is that if the robot hits a wall and stays at the same X and Y coordinates, the filtered odometry shows the robot still moving forward. I think this behavior is due to the filter relying only on the encoders for X and Y. What should I do to correct this error? Maybe using the IMU's acceleration?
This is my ekf.yaml file:
ekf_filter_node:
ros__parameters:
use_sim_time: false
frequency: 50.0
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false

odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_footprint
world_frame: odom

    #x     , y     , z,
    #roll  , pitch , yaw,
    #vx    , vy    , vz,
    #vroll , vpitch, vyaw,
    #ax    , ay    , az

odom0: /odom/unfiltered
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               true, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false

imu0: /imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              true, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              true, false, false]
imu0_queue_size: 10
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true

imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

use_control: false


Yes. If you enable the accelerometer data to be fused then this should override data from the wheels and the EKF will figure out that the robot can't be moving.
However I'm not sure if you will still end up with some residual error - by that I mean the X&Y coordinates move a bit whilst the EKF comes to a "decision".
You could compensate for that by holding a history of coordinates - then "lookback" to one that you know to be good.
Also fusing other sensor data like lidar would help - the "image" won't change
Hope that helps
Mark

You mean the acceleration in the last Row (ax, ay, az)?  Because I already tried it and with the ay I have a strong drift and I disabled it and with ax I still don't have this behavior. Should I turn ax to true for both odometry and IMU matrix or only on the IMU. (Maybe when I tried I did it only for the IMU)


The only problem is that if the robot hits a wall

I'd probably start with fixing this. ;)
But re: the EKF behaviour, it's important to keep in mind that the EKF is going to trust the sensor data it's being given. In this case, your wheel encoders are reporting the same covariance before the robot strikes the wall and after the robot strikes the wall, but the latter is not accurate. In a perfect world, you'd recognise that you had collided with the wall (maybe by seeing a voltage increase to the motors) and inflate the wheel odometry covariance accordingly. But that's not going to be straightforward.
The idea of also fusing the acceleration data to help with this is a good one, but note that the acceleration data is being integrated to obtain velocity, and the velocity data is getting fused directly. This means the velocity data will have a much more profound effect on your state estimate than the acceleration data. In other words, I wouldn't expect it to do much unless you do some very careful tuning of the acceleration covariance, the linear velocity covariance in your wheel encoders, and the process noise covariance for linear X acceleration. But even then, I wouldn't have a lot of hope.
Note that you have X acceleration set to true for your wheel encoders, but that's meaningless for that sensor type. You also have X velocity set to true for your IMU, and that is also not going to be used (IMU messages do not have X velocity).
Also, you didn't provide any sensor message input examples, but if your IMU is not mounted in a neutral position with +X facing forward, you'll need to provide a transform from the IMU frame to your base_link_frame.
